# Does java respect PATH env variable when resolves .jar filename?

Tags: java, environment-variables

This is what I have in `PATH`:

```
PATH=/opt/ClosureCompiler:/home/vmadmin/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

There is a `compiler.jar` in `/opt/ClosureCompiler`, but when I call

```
java -jar compiler.jar
```

I get

```
Unable to access jarfile compiler.jar
```

Though `java -jar /opt/ClosureCompiler/compiler.jar` works just fine.

So, can java follow the `PATH` for filenames resolving? If so - what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no provision in the `java` executable for searching a list of directories for the .jar file. Write a wrapper script that executes `java` with the full path to the .jar.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec java -jar /opt/ClosureCompiler/compiler.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to make the jar excutable using `chmod +x compiler.jar`.  Then you can run it from your `PATH` as follows:

```
compiler.jar --help
```

These are a couple of other options to use the `java` command to run the file.

Java uses the CLASSPATH to find classes and other resources.  The classpath can contain jars and directories.  Java will search the classpath for resources.  Define an environment variable containing the path(s) you want searched.  The path seperator is ; on Windows and : on most other systems.  This will work for classes on the command line, but not jars.  If you read the `manifest` of `compiler.jar` you can write a short `Compiler` class which invokes the main class.  Alternatively, just invoke the main class directly as specifed in the manifest instead of `Compiler` (as specified below).

You may already have a classpath defined.  Try `echo $CLASSPATH` to see if it is.  Try

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/ClosureCompiler:/opt/ClosureCompiler/compiler.jar
java Compiler
```

or for closure (other jars will have a different main class).

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/ClosureCompiler/compiler.jar
java com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner
```

You should define your `CLASSPATH` where you added `/opt/ClosureCompiler` to your path.   You don't need it `/opt/ClosureCompiler` in your path.

This is a sample Compiler.java file.

```
import com.google.javascript.jscomp.CommandLineRunner;
public class Compiler {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        CommandLineRunner.main( args );
    }
}
```

It can be compiled with the command `javac -cp compiler.jar Compiler.java`.

Comment: In order to get this to work you'd need to add the .jar itself to `$CLASSPATH` and then specify the main class yourself, thereby eliminating one of the main (no pun intended) advantages of creating a .jar file in the first place.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Simplified that option as suggested.